# Problema ao usar Tabs Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando utilizar o componente tabs do bootstrap, porém não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, já peguei diversos exemplos, mas não consegui fazer funcionar.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">Totais por Filiais</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">Informações sobre pagamento</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab">Observações</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
                            Tab 1
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
                            Tab 2
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_3">
                           Tab 3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Quando clico, permanece sempre na primeira aba, não troca para as outras. alguém sabe onde está o erro, ou se falta algum código?

Comment: A princípio seu código parece estar certo amigo, segue o link do bootply com seu código: http://www.bootply.com/1XZyeROFwe

Comment: O erro não me parece estar no front-end. Mas verifique o caminho do seu script e css pra ver se está tudo nos conformes...

Comment: Já verifiquei o caminho dos scripts, mas ainda tá na mesma, não tenho mais ideia porque não está funcionando :/

Comment: Os div estão certinhos @Geferson? que pelo que contei aqui, falta o div do row...Tá batendo certo ai?

Comment: Ta sim @Daniel, Achei o problema. não tinha me tocado, mas coloquei a lib do bootstrap antes do Jquery, e o bootstrap usa o Jquery, agora coloquei o Jquery antes e está funcionando. desatenção minha, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: JQuery sempre tem que vir antes do Bootstrap, se não ele não funciona direito, buga tudo inclusive o carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As libs estavam invertidas, como o bootstrap depende do Jquery, coloquei a do jQuery antes e tudo passou a funcionar.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```